# Multiple bluetooth chipsets?

Tags: drivers, bluetooth

In my quest to connect my bluetooth headphone (Phiaton MS 530) to my laptop (HP Probook 650) I wanted to update the bluetooth drivers.
If I read [this datasheet](http://h71016.www7.hp.com/dstore/html/pdfs/US_CA_English_HP_ProBook_650_Datasheet.pdf) correctly there are multiple bluetooth chipsets in this laptop.

Is this possible?
Do I need to update the drivers for all of them? Won't they collide?

Wireless support WLAN:

```
Atheros 802.11b/g/n (1x1)9
Atheros 802.11b/g/n (1x1) and Bluetooth 4.0 Combo9
Broadcom 802.11a/b/g/n (2x2) and Bluetooth 4.0 Combo9
Intel Centrino Advanced N-6205 802.11a/b/g/n (2x2)9
Intel Centrino Advanced N-6235 802.11a/b/g/n and Bluetooth 4.0 Combo9
Intel Wireless N-7260 802.11a/b/g/n AC (2x2) and Bluetooth 4.0 Combo9
WWAN:
HP hs3110 HSPA+ Mobile Broadband10,15,23
HP lt4111 LTE/EV-DO/HSPA+ Mobile Broadband10,15,23
```

Listed drivers on HP's drivers download page:

- http://h20564.www2.hp.com/hpsc/swd/public/detail?sp4ts.oid=5405142&swItemId=ob_126765_1&swEnvOid=4060
- http://h20564.www2.hp.com/hpsc/swd/public/detail?sp4ts.oid=5405142&swItemId=ob_141075_1&swEnvOid=4060
- http://h20564.www2.hp.com/hpsc/swd/public/detail?sp4ts.oid=5405142&swItemId=ob_132205_1&swEnvOid=4060

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The different chipsets are options you can choose when ordering the notebook as custom configured. In your laptop there will be only one chipset supporting both WLAN and bluetooth. You can find out the chipset used in the device manager.

Open the device manager with following steps:

- On start menu, choose Administrative Tools -> Computer management
- In the link pane, choose System -> Device Manager
- In the right pane, open the node Bluetooth.

Comment: The device manager showed Generic Bluetooth (windows default), I just started installing all the driver packages one by one until one of them didn't fail. Now it shows that it's the Intel one.